# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre variable y parámetro?

Tags: java

Entrando en este mundo de escribir código mediante java. me tope con los métodos, una sección de código con nombre a la que se puede ejecutar mediante una call statement tantas veces sea necesaria. cada vez que la funcion se ejecuta, le puedo pasar valores mediante los parametros, segun las diferentes fuentes que he leído son como variables, que puedes usar justo como cualquier otra variable dentro de la función y pues cuando se ejecute, la variable se evalúa en los lugares donde lo indique en el código en las diferentes statements que tenga dentro de la función.

¿Hay alguna diferencia entre un parámetro y una variable aparte de que la asignación de valores en los parámetros debe de ser cuando llame a la función entre los paréntesis?

```
public static void sumar(int numero1,int numero2){
   System.out.println("La suma es: " + (numero1+numero2));
} 

public static void main(String[] args){
   sumar(1,2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una variable puede ser declarada de manera global (fuera de los métodos) y de manera local (dentro de los métodos). Si bien los parámetros se consideran como locales, su inicialización no solo se puede dar en la llamada a la función como por ejemplo;

```
suma(1,2);
```

Sino que también, puedes mandar variables, como por ejemplo;

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
suma(a,b);
```

A grandes rasgos, la diferencia es que los parámetros se comportan en un ámbito local, en cambio, las variables pueden comportarse de manera global y local.